# How to stop Private Blockchain Synchronizing

Tags: mastering-ethereum

How do I stop a private blockchain synchronizing when I am in Geth Console, can't enter a command line due to continuous synchro.

geth --datadir ./datadir_node_0 console

Answer (score 0):

Try with this shortcut: **CTRL+C**